# union of two locally connected sets is still locally connected

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are spaces of $X$ and $A$ and $B$　are locally connected and $A\cap B\neq \phi$,Must $A\cup B$ locally connected?

Part of my thought:Suppose $x\in A$,  $ x\notin B$,for any open neighborhood of $x$ in $A\cup B$,$U$,there exists an open set in $X$ ,$V$,s.t. $U=(V\cap A)\cup(V\cap B)$.Considering open set in $A$,$V\cap A$,there exists a connected open connected neighborhood in $A$ contained in $V\cap A$.But this open connected neighborhood in $A$ may be not an open neighborhood in $A\cup B$. Can we disprove this statement from this detail?

Comment: @bof their intersection should be nonempty

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\mathbb R^2$ and let
$$A=\{(x,y):x\gt0\text{ and }y=\sin\frac1x\},$$
$$B=\{(x,y):x=0\text{ or }x=1\text{ or }y=2\}.$$
Then $A$ and $B$ are connected (which you did not require but perhaps intended) and locally connected, and $A\cap B=\{(1,\sin1)\}\ne\emptyset,$ but $A\cup B$ is not locally connected.